No publishable resources for tag []. Laravel - Intervention Integration
i am trying to install Image Intervention V3 to my Laravel project.
So i runned this command first:composer require intervention/image
Then when i try run next step whic is:
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Intervention\Image\Laravel\ServiceProvider"
It says: INFO  No publishable resources for tag [].
I am new on Laravel and following one Youtube serie, i am stucked here. Anyone can help? Thanks.

If this is laravel 11, you can just run php artisan vendor:publish and it will show you a list where you can pick and choose what you publish. Try finding the package in that list.
